# How to use 'if not exists' on MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xampp, exists

How to use `if not exists` in MySQL database.

```
create schema if not exists appkasir;

use appkasir;

create table if not exists admin (
    id int(11) not null auto_increment,
    nama varchar(20) not null,
    no_telp varchar(20) null,
    alamat varchar(50) null,
    email varchar(50) null,
    primary key (id)
);
```

Comment: The code looks like correct one. What is the problem? Do you receive some error message? if so then post its complete text.

Comment: Please explain what doesn't work or what error do you get.

Answer (score 0):

You give no congret error message. I think it's not an error of `if exists` but maybe of the primary key.

Look at [MySQL reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html).

Try:

```sql
create schema if not exists appkasir;

use appkasir;

create table if not exists admin (
    id int(11) not null auto_increment primary key,
    nama varchar(20) not null,
    no_telp varchar(20) null,
    alamat varchar(50) null,
    email varchar(50) null
);
```